# Instance of trait throws null pointer

Tags: scala

Why does a null pointer exception occur in the code below?

```
object Test extends App{
    trait MyTrait[A]{ self =>
        val seq: Seq[A]
        val size = seq.size // null pointer here
    }

    val p = new MyTrait[Int]{
        val seq = Seq(1,2,3)
    }
}
```

If I change the size field to lazy then it's ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fields are initialized in the order they are mixed in--so first everything in the trait happens, and then the `val` is assigned to `Seq(1,2,3)` (since you're essentially mixing in an anonymous trait).

As you have discovered, `lazy val` is often a way out of this mess: you don't actually call `seq.size` until you need it, which is after you have populated the `seq` field.

Answer (score 6):

The style recommendation is to avoid vals in traits, in favor of defs and lazy vals, because of init order land mines.

Sample conversation:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scala-user/nrOrjPOYmb0

Comment: Thanks.  Like the idea of using def, seems tidier.

Comment: @Pengin - I assumed you were using a `val` to cache the value.  `List` for example takes `O(n)` time to find the size--it has to traverse the list.  In that case a `def` is not of any use in speeding things up.

Comment: @RexKerr - Ah yes, I confused different code with the simple example given here.